# CSS Selector for sibling

Tags: css

How do I select the radio from a list of tr's where the only unique element is 'Some unique value'?

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="myradioname" value="4" onclick="myevent">
  </td>
  <td>
    Some value
  </td>
  <td>Some unique value</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So... you want to select the radio, inside a tr... that contains a td, that contains the value 'Some unique value'?  If that's the case.... no can do.

Answer (score 3):

While this cannot be done using pure CSS, it can be achieved using jQuery's [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector..

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2o7eg6y8/2/)

The selector you're looking for is:

```
$("tr:contains('Some unique value')").find('input[type="radio"]')
```

First you look for a `<tr>` that contains 'Some unique value', then you find `input[type="radio"]` within it.

Works like a charm. In the jsFiddle only the radio near 'Some unique value' gets checked on page load using this selector.

**Notes:**

1. There are other ways you can go about it, for e.g finding the `<td>` that contains 'Some unique value' then looking for the `<input>` inside its siblings.. However I think the way presented here is most efficient.
2. If you can select the table first and search only the rows inside it do it, for it will run faster.. e.g: `$("#myTable tr:contains('Some unique value')").find('input[type="radio"]')`.
3. **If you still want to do it using CSS alone** I would recommend viewing your server side code and using a conditional statement for adding a class to that specific `<tr>` for example `class="special"` then adding a CSS rule like so: `.special input[type="radio"]{...}`